# ndk undefined reference to `(function_name)' in SWIG wrapper file

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, swig

I have been trying to build a shared object for [ngspice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/) simulation library to be used in an android application, I was able to create the shared object using ndk-build but only if I don't add the wrapper file created by SWIG as a source file in Android.mk.

The problem is I get an error when building Android.mk

Here is the contents of the SWIG interface file:

```
%module NGSpiceModule
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "include/ngspice/sharedspice.h"
%}

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "include/ngspice/sharedspice.h"
```

And here is the header file ([sharedspice.h](http://pastebin.com/q7mcqNVD))

When I create the wrapper file using command:

```
swig -java -package package_name -outdir src/java_classes_path -o jni/ngspicemodule_wrap.c jni/ngspicemodule.i
```

I get a long file ([ngspicemodule_wrap.c](http://pastebin.com/YfbtV2uR)) to interface the whole header file contents.

Android.mk file contents:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := NGSpiceModule

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
ngspicemodule_wrap.c \
.
.
...rest of the source files

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

when I try to build the Android.mk file using:

```
ndk-build v=1
```

I get this error:

```
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/NGSpiceModule/ngspicemodule_wrap.o: In function `Java_packageName_NGSpiceModuleJNI_ngSpice_1Init':projectPath/jni/ngspicemodule_wrap.c:1197: undefined reference to `ngSpice_Init'
```

which as you can see is complaining that it can't find the function, and the error appears for every other function.

The thing is that there are many typedefs for structs and callbacks in the header file but it is not complaining about them in the wrapper file only about the functions.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.